# How to get html repsonse from website which redirects to login.microsoft?

Tags: c#, authentication, httprequest, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

I was using the blow code to obtain the html of a web page using URL into variable `strOutput`

```
Dim strURL As String = "https://example.net/exmplepage.aspx"
Dim strOutput As String = ""
Dim wrResponse As WebResponse
Dim wrRequest As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
wrRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
wrResponse = wrRequest.GetResponse()           
Dim stream As Stream = wrResponse.GetResponseStream()

Using sr As New StreamReader(stream)
 strOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
 sr.Close()
End Using
```

Unfortunately there were some changes to the website. Now when I access the URL though browser, it first redirects to *https://login.microsoftonline.com/*, and after few seconds automatically redirects back the correct URL. But when I try using the code I am getting the HTML of the Microsoft page into `strOutput`

[image]

In the above screenshot, I opened the URL in incognito mode, so its stuck in the Microsoft login page, which is what my httprequest returns. If I open the URL normally in browser, it authenticates automatically and redirects to the correct page.

How will I modify my code, so it will fetch the correct html response, of https://example.net/exmplepage.aspx ?

**Update**

I was able to use another dirty workaround to avoid this problem.
I loaded the url into a webbrowser control, and then took the document text of the control. That gave me the required html of the target page

Comment: This is not about Windows-Authentication, but about Single SignOn (oAuth). Your webclient (HttpRequest) is not authenticated, so you can add the DefaultNetworkCredentials all you want, but it will not help you. Apparantly the webpage you try to access is protected by this SSO - so your client should authenticate before you can read that page.

Comment: Is it possible to do that authentication in code?

Comment: Yes it is, Google for keywords like SAML, SSO authentication etc for your specific case. This is not something that can be explained in one answer and/or one comment.